# Obtaining Worker ID from MTurk Using React

Tags: reactjs, mechanicalturk

I have built a web app using React and want to be able to capture the worker ID. Is there a way to do this with React?

Comment: Every participant who performs your HIT on Amazon Mechanical Turk gets automatically assigned an id called "Worker ID". Since it is generated from Amazon, I am interested in knowing if I can get this ID via React

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your React code will run in an iframe. The iframe URL will look like this:

https://www.mturkcontent.com/dynamic/hit?assignmentId=382M90RTU7DNS1COHERG0VIJ7IGUEQ&hitId=DX6EGJKFBK3NSCTNUR39O8F69WRA5J&workerId=A3IWRVNFT1T83W&turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com

You can retrieve the worker id from the query string. It's `A3IWRVNFT1T83W` in this example.